# Laravel Tests with Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I created a simple HTTP Test for my application:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\Author;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Testing\Fluent\AssertableJson;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AuthorControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->seed();
    }

    /**
     * Test the Index Route of Author Controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_index_route()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/api/authors');

        $response->assertJson(
            fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
            $json->has(2)->first(
                function (AssertableJson $json) {
                    $json->hasAll(['id', 'name', 'description',]);
                    $json->missingAll(['email', 'avatar', 'twitter', 'password', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
                }
            )
        );

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertSuccessful();

        $response->assertJsonCount(2);
    }
}
```

Here the response from the server:

```json
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Official Author",
            "description": "Author Description"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "User",
            "description": "User Description"
        }
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/authors?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "next_page_url": null,
    "path": "http://localhost:8000/api/authors",
    "per_page": 3,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 2
}
```

So... I can't found a solution to get just the `data` attribute and use the `hasAll()` and `missingAll()` functions on Tests.

I've searched for an entire day, but nothing. The only solution i founded is converting the json to array, make loops and checking the keys, but i think there is a possible using the hasAll()`and`missingAll()` functions, which is simpler.

And if have any other simple solution, I would like to know how it is implemented.

Comment: This question is no more clear than the last time you asked it. What conditions are you trying to test for?

Comment: How can i use the functions `hasAll()` and `missingAll()` inside the `data` attribute

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

I looked through the docs and it seems like it supports dot annotation and can provide key as the first parameter on `has()`.

```
->assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
    $json->has('data', 2)
         ->has('data.0', fn ($json) =>
             $json->hasAll(['id', 'name', 'description',]);
             $json->missingAll(['email', 'avatar', 'twitter', 'password', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
         );
);
```

Comment: No... Return an Error:
`Root level does not have the expected size.
  Failed asserting that actual size 9 matches expected size 2.`

Comment: thats because you are calling has before, scope. I will change my answer, but i will guess you have to debug some in this process when i don't have the code to look through

Comment: I Tried that, but return an Error: `Method Illuminate\Testing\Fluent\AssertableJson::scope does not exist.`

Comment: Oh scope is a protected function found this snippet from the doc see if it helps :) think the big challenge is this feature is quite new and most people not have any experience with it yet.

Comment: Now returns the error: `Unexpected properties were found on the root level.
  Failed asserting that two arrays are identical.`. I Verify that the first `$json->has('data', 2)` is the problem.

Comment: yh, i actually implemented a similar approach on a project i work on now. When you use has, you have to assert that all keys are there.

Comment: So... I was trying to solve the problem, and nothing. I already searched literally all the internet, but no results.

Any idea?

Comment: As said with that approach you have to assert all the keys

Comment: Can you do an example? Like i tried the example. but the tests continue to returns fail

Comment: The Fail Message: `Unexpected properties were found on the root level.
  Failed asserting that two arrays are identical.` They expect an empty array, but the actual is the all response json (current_page, first_page_url, from, next_page_url, path, per_page, prev_page_url, to)